# Word meaning “not work-related”

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

My only email account has got unmanageably cluttered and it’s time for a change. Rather than go through the hassle of unsubscribing to hundreds of services I’ll just give a few friends a new address. I’ve therefore decided to fork my correspondence into two groups: work related and personal. I like the idea, but am not wild about the account name.

*firstname.lastname.personal@gmail.com*

It sounds like I use it for personal ads and am keeping my main email separate from strangers I’m trying to hook up with.

I don’t know if that’s just my perception or not though.

Is this connotation actually implied? (Maybe this is opinion based, however it isn’t really my main question).

#### Is there a better word to suffix this account that indicates it isn’t for work?

*tagged as single-word-request as that is preferable, but not, I guess, absolutely critical if the candidate is otherwise perfect.

Comment: If you'd used 'personals' I could see your point. But personally (!) I don't see any problem with your choice here. I think it's just you (-:

Comment: “@gmail.com” suggests ‘not work’ all by itself. :P

Comment: @JimMack heheh well thanks, that confidence is maybe all I need to pull the trigger on this address.

Comment: This Q borders on [off-topic.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) i.e. "naming, especially computer stuff."

Comment: @Cascabel I don't see what you've quoted in what you've linked.

Comment: Scroll down a bit..."Naming, including naming programming variables/classes " As I said, only borderline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especially in the workplace, it's very common to hear of [*work-life balance*](https://www.forbes.com/sites/deborahlee/2014/10/20/6-tips-for-better-work-life-balance/#23c0ab2629ff) (Forbes).

Therefore, I would suggest:

> firstname.lastname.life@gmail.com

Alternatively, you can be at *work* or you can be at *home* (regardless of if you are in the same location).

So:

> firstname.lastname.home@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Not an English based answer, but another way of addressing (see what I did there) the problem. A little known (?) feature of email addresses is that you can append "+string" to the addressee and it will still be delivered. So, for example, if you are **first.last@gmail.com** then you can send email to **first.last+private@gmail.com** and it will be delivered.

You can then set up a filter to automatically put these in a different folder (or label them, as gmail does it).

That will let you have an unlimited number of email addresses with the ability to automatically sort them.

Comment: But take note it doesn't work on all websites. I tried this on Quora (or some other website, I forgot) and it recognized my email address. Just saying.

Comment: If this relies on the sender appending the +*tag*, consistency will be problematic.

Comment: Yeah the tip for the `+` + `filter` is not super useful, but I kinda like the suggestion of _private_. I'm not sure why; it's not like I publish my work-related mail, but for some reason I like this option.

Comment: The `+filtername` part of the question may or may not work for OP depending on the email account, and the website(s) they use it at, however I'm upvoting because private seems like a good fit for 'non-work-related', e.g. "I have my work life, and I have my private life."

Answer (score 0):

Do you think **Social** would fit?

*fname.lastname.social@gmail.com*

Comment: My concern would be that *social* might be too restrictive. There are other reasons of communication outside work that, anyway, would not be classified as *social*.

Comment: Adding "social" to the end of your email address makes it seem like this is an email address that's separate from your work and/or private email address(es), which is specifically for use at social networking sites like Facebook, Instagram, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would find

> fname.lname.otherthanwork@sthmail.com

a nice way to put it. But of course this is a bit long and may annoy people who have to type the address entirely (rather than relying on auto-complete). In this case,

> fname.lname.notwork@sthmail.com

may be acceptable. It also looks okay because the t functions as a visual divider between the two words.

Or, if you really want to use this only for your friends, why not

> fname.lname.friends@sthmail.com